# Which algorithm will find the path closest to zero?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

So I have a graph and I want to find (having the weight of each edge - which is either negative or positive) the path that reach zero (or is closest to it) by adding each weight.

I need that to calculate which path in a function cleans up the stack fully.

Which algorithm should I use - I have found about the Bellman–Ford algorithm because it allows negative indices but I'm not sure if it'll do the job.

Comment: So your graph is directed? Can it have loops? (Cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph )

Comment: @StinkingBishop I think so - yes.

Comment: "Yes" for directed or "yes" for loops?

Comment: I mean I think it could have loops. But there will always be a path to the end.

Answer (score 0):

The question of whether a path with total absolute weight $\leq k$ exists is NP-complete. That it is in NP is hopefully clear (addition is fast); to see that it is NP-complete, let us reduce subset-sum to your problem. Let us first do $k=0$ (i.e., does a weight-zero path exist) for simplicity.

Suppose that we have an instance of subset-sum with set $S = \{s_1, \ldots, s_m\}$ and potential sum $n$. Now build a graph with $|S| + 1$ vertices: between the $i$th and $(i+1)$th vertex add an edge with weight $s_i$, as well as an edge with weight 0. (You can use an additional vertex with two edges in case your problem does not allow for multiple edges between vertices.) Finally, add an additional target vertex, connected only to the final vertex by an edge with weight $-n$. Then a path from the first vertex to the target vertex of weight 0 is precisely a subset of $S$ that adds up to $n$.

You can reduce to the case for general $k$ by simply multiplying all these weights in the constructed graph by $k+1$.

Therefore you should not expect there to be a fast algorithm in general for the problem you have described.

Comment: Is this problem in NP if the path is not necessarily required to be simple? I can imagine a graph where there’s a single enormous edge and a cycle with tiny negative net cost, where the normal certificate of “here’s the path in question” wouldn’t be polynomially-sized.